# Using google drive "save to drive" button within Angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, google-drive-api

I am having trouble using google's ["Save to drive"](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive) button within my angualrjs project.

I can use the sample code just fine but am unsure how to integrate it into my angularjs project. My first attempt was to add:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

in my `index.html` (the root template file for my angular project). Then to add the save to drive div to a sub-template:

```
   <div class="g-savetodrive"
   data-src="data/test.php"
   data-filename="t2.csv"
   data-sitename="My Company Name">
   </div>
```

Unfortunately I couldn't get the button to render this way. I'm certain I'm just missing out on some basic angular knowledge but can't locate specifically what I need to know.

Comment: Please check your console error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I expected I was just using the Google API incorrectly within Angular. I was able to solve my problem by using the "Explicit Render" option listed.

So in index.html:

```
   <head>
    ...
    <script>
      window.___gcfg = {
        parsetags: 'explicit'
      };
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
```

And in the template file:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="render-link">Render the Save to Drive button</a>
    <div id="savetodrive-div"></div>
```

Finally, in the template's controller:

```
function renderSaveToDrive() {
          gapi.savetodrive.render('savetodrive-div', {
            src: '/yourFileSource.html',
            filename: 'theTargetfile.txt',
            sitename: 'Your company name'
          });
        }
        document.getElementById('render-link').addEventListener('click', renderSaveToDrive);
```

Note: you can just render on page load instead of when clicking the "Render to Save to Drive Button" link. Just get rid of 
`<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="render-link">Render the Save to Drive button</a>` in the template and `document.getElementById('render-link').addEventListener('click', renderSaveToDrive);` in the controller. Then call `renderSaveToDrive();` directly in the controller.